# Reserve a Classroom. SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The server has to reserve a classroom 30 minutes, 1 hour or an hour and a half.

```
create database schooldb;

use schooldb;


CREATE TABLE `classrooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `reserves` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `InitialTime` time NOT NULL,
  `finalTime` time NOT NULL,
  `classrooms_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_AA1DAB0188E95B37` (`classrooms_id_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AA1DAB0188E95B37` FOREIGN KEY (`classrooms_id_id`) REFERENCES `classrooms` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

describe classrooms;

'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'tipo','varchar(64)','NO','',NULL,''


describe reserves;

'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'date','date','NO','',NULL,''
'InitialTime','time','NO','',NULL,''
'finalTime','time','NO','',NULL,''
'classrooms_id_id','int(11)','NO','MUL',NULL,''


INSERT INTO `schooldb`.`classrooms` (`id`, `tipo`) VALUES ('1', 'Physics');
INSERT INTO `schooldb`.`classrooms` (`id`, `tipo`) VALUES ('2', 'Circuits');

INSERT INTO `schooldb`.`reserves` (`id`, `date`, `InitialTime`, `finalTime`, `classrooms_id_id`) VALUES ('1', '2016-05-18', '09:30', '11:00', '1');
INSERT INTO `schooldb`.`reserves` (`id`, `date`, `InitialTime`, `finalTime`, `classrooms_id_id`) VALUES ('2', '2016-05-18', '12:00', '13:30', '1');
INSERT INTO `schooldb`.`reserves` (`id`, `date`, `InitialTime`, `finalTime`, `classrooms_id_id`) VALUES ('3', '2016-05-18', '19:00', '20:00', '1');
```

I need to get all ranges of free hours and encapsulate it in a JSON package with PHP. For example:

```
select * from reserves;

'1','2016-05-18','09:30:00','11:00:00','1'
'2','2016-05-18','12:00:00','13:30:00','1'
'3','2016-05-18','19:00:00','20:00:00','1'

select * from reserves where date="2016-05-18" and InitialTime <= "09:30" and finalTime >= "10:00";

'1','2016-05-18','09:30:00','11:00:00','1'
```

Ok!! It works!!

Now:

```
select * from reserves where date="2016-05-18" and InitialTime <= "18:30" and finalTime >= "19:30";
```

No results!! Error!!

How can I make it.

Thank you!

Comment: There are no rows that meet that condition though. The first two rows have `InitialTime <= '18:30'` but fail the `finalTime` check, while the third row has `finalTime >= '19:30'` but fails the `InitialTime` check...

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably just store date and time as a single entity

Comment: And how can i make that comparation